# How do I pass several lists of 'allowed' IDs to filter a Lucene search?

Tags: java, filter, lucene

I need to return just the documents that a user has access to from a Lucene search. There are several types of data in this Lucene index. I can get a list of IDs from a database that make up the 'allowed' subset for each type of data. So how can I use this two attibutes('type' and 'entity_id') to make a customer filter? I am using Java.

```
/**
 * @param idMap key: type; value: IDs
 */
public MyCustomerFilter(Map<Integer, Set<Long>> idMap){
    this.idMap = idMap;
}

@Override
public DocIdSet getDocIdSet(IndexReader reader) throws Exception {
    OpenBitSet bitSet = new OpenBitSet(reader.maxDoc());
    Set<Integer result = permit(reader);
    for (Integer position : result) {
        bitSet.set(position);
    }
    return bitSet;
}

private Set<Integer> permit(IndexReader reader) {

    Set<Integer> result = new HashSet<>();

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Set<Long>> entry : idMap.entrySet()) {
        Integer type = entry.getKey();
        Set<Long> idSet = entry.getValue();

        Set<Integer> typeResult = new HashSet<>();
        Set<Integer> idResult = new HashSet<>();

        int[] docs = new int[1];
        int[] freqs= new int[1];

        try {
            int count = reader.termDocs(new Term("type", 
                String.valueOf(type))).read(docs, freqs);
            if (count > 0) {
                typeResult.add(docs[0]);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            // ignore
        }

        for(Long id : idSet) {
            docs = new int[1];
            freqs= new int[1];
            try {
                int count = reader.termDocs(new Term("entityId", 
                    String.valueOf(id))).read(docs, freqs);
                if (count > 0) {
                    idResult.add(docs[0]);
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                // ignore
            }
        }

        for (Integer i : idResult){
            for (Integer j : typeResult) {
                if (i.intValue == j.intValue) {
                    result.add(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return result ;
}
```

Comment: yes, you could do that, what did you try so far?

Comment: I am using Lucene-3.6.2. I cannot understand the function getDocIdSet(IndexReader reader) in org.apache.lucene.search.Filter.java well. I tried to create a customer filter. In the getDocIdSet() function, I tried to get the union of these several types of data. Please see the codes in the question.